# En una sentencia de inserccion sql, es seguro mostrar la estructura de mi tabla?

Tags: sql, nodejs, postgresql

estoy usando nodejs y pg, y tengo que insertar un usuario nuevo, y tengo que mostrar la estructura de mi tabla en la sentencia sql, eso es seguro ? o alguien se puede infiltrar a mi BBDD ? (soy nuevo y estoy comenzando a programar)

Aqui el codigo:

```
const createUser = async (user) => {
    
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10)
        const query = {
            // aqui muestro la estructura de mi tabla
            text: `
                       INSERT INTO public."Usuario"(
                       "idUsuario", nombres, apellidos, email, contrasena, "idRol")
                       VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING *`,
            values: [user.idUser, user.names, user.lastname, user.email, user.password, user.idRol]
        }
        await pool.query(query)
    
}
```

Comment: Eso esta en tu servidor no? a donde es que lo mostrar?

Comment: Claro, eso estará en el servidor de mi API REST, lo planeaba subir a HEROKU

Comment: O sea.. esta en el mismo servidor donde esta tu base de datos... si alguien obtiene acceso, obtiene acceso a todas las cosas ;)

Comment: ahh no, la BBDD esta en otro servidor (entiendo que HEROKU, lo monta asi, una para la api, otra para el postgres)

Comment: Por eso es que se prefiere el uso de procedimientos almacenados. Así se agrega una capa extra de seguridad. Aunque lo que mencionas no es completamente peligroso por si mismo.

Comment: Como por si mismo ? osea pueden infiltrarse?

Comment: no. no pueden bajar ese codigo, salvo que bajen ese codigo accediendo a tu sitio y bajando el codigo fuente desde tu sitio.. pero si entraron ahi, tu base de datos es el menor de tus problemas...

Answer (score 0):

Termine por dejar el sql en linea (mostrar la estructura de mi tabla en la sentencia), los valores parametrizados de pg (postgres npm) [estan probados contra ataques de inyeccion sql](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries)

> Si está pasando parámetros a sus consultas, querrá evitar que la cadena concatene parámetros en el texto de la consulta directamente. Esto puede (y a menudo lo hace) conducir a vulnerabilidades de inyección de SQL. node-postgres admite consultas parametrizadas, pasando el texto de la consulta sin alterar , así como sus parámetros al servidor PostgreSQL, donde los parámetros se sustituyen de forma segura en la consulta con código de sustitución de parámetros probado en batalla dentro del propio servidor.

Con eso, mi tabla esta segura contra inyecciones sql, al menos por ese lado.